# Python 3.6: detect highest/lowest values from calculated averages from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a program that collects grades, takes the average, and then prints the highest and lowest averages along with the user's name. I am using code from a former week's assignment that took user input and calculated the averages, but I'm struggling to figure out how to detect high/low values from those calculated averages. I also am unsure where to start in reprinting the associated name information once I detect those high/low values. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def main():

    numuser=eval(input("How many users are there?: "))
    numgrade=eval(input("How many grades will there be for each user?: "))
    usercount=0
    gradecount=0

    grade(numuser,numgrade,usercount,gradecount)

def grade(nu,ng,uc,gc):
    name=[]
    while uc <= nu:
        first=input("Please enter the student's first name: ")
        last=input("Please enter the student's last name: ")
        name.append(last)
        ID=input("Please enter the student's ID: ")
        gradetot=0

        total=[]
        grades=[]
        while gc < ng:
            gradeval=eval(input("Please enter the grade: "))
            total.append(gradeval)
            gradetot=gradetot+gradeval
            gc=gc+1

            avg=gradetot/gc
            grades.append(avg)

            low=min(grades)
            high=max(grades)

        nu=nu-1
        uc=uc+1
        gc=0

        print("The average grade for", first, last, ID, "is :", avg)

    if uc>nu:
        print("The lowest average is ", low, "and the highest average is", high)

main()
```

Comment: Post sample input for your program , no one knows here the `id' or 'grade' parameter accept only int or string or mix etc same for other parameters, post sample input and expected output.

Comment: Have you learned for-loops yet? It would greatly reduce the amount of moving parts in your code. But I'm pretty sure you need to use `min` and `max` on `average`, which is a *list* of your numbers, not on `avg`, which is a single number. i.e. instead of `low = min(avg)` you want `low = min(average)`. Note, you should post the errors you are getting. Maybe a better name is `grades` not `average`.

Comment: I'd advise a slightly different approach, read the student/grade information into a list of dictionaries (each student info being a dictionary), and then [sort](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) that list by average grade. That way, you can at the end simply print the first and last element of your list, and have the full student info available for easy printing.

Comment: To the first comment, so sorry. First/last/ID are student info, could be anything, i.e. John Smith 87. Parameters are for number of students and grades per student you'll be entering, as well as the counters for both. If the code is really redundant, it's because I'm completing assignments for an intro course -- so it's part professor requirements (e.g. have to have 3 functions for this, have to use parameters, etc.), part me not having complete command over the code.

Comment: To the second comment, I changed it around and it worked partway. I didn't get an error from Python, but it only reported back one correct value for the high/low. Updating the code in the description now

Comment: @Hannah: Please check my answer and let me know feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the data of student name and their average grade in dictionary. Then you can retrieve using dictionary methods

1. You are using in >= in main loop which is iterating more times which means asks user to enter more records
2. If you want to print user name along with their grade information you have to store them in dictionary

   `def main():`

   ```
   numuser=eval(input("How many users are there?: "))
   numgrade=eval(input("How many grades will there be for each user?: "))
   usercount=0
   gradecount=0

   grade(numuser,numgrade,usercount,gradecount)
   ```

   `def grade(nu,ng,uc,gc):
       dct={}
       while uc < nu:
           first=input("Please enter the student's first name: ")
           last=input("Please enter the student's last name: ")
           ID=input("Please enter the student's ID: ")
           gradetot=0`

   ```
       total=[]
       while gc < ng:
           gradeval=eval(input("Please enter the grade: "))
           total.append(gradeval)

           average=[]
           gradetot=gradetot+gradeval
           average.append(gradetot)
           avg=gradetot/(gc+1)
           gc=gc+1
           dct[first+last]=avg  
           #Getting errors here with trying to find a mechanism to detect values from a calculated average
           #nu=nu-1
       uc=uc+1
       gc=0


   print dct    
   maxkey, maxvalue = max(dct.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])

   print("The highest grade obtained by", maxkey, "is :",maxvalue )
   ```

   `"""
           nu=nu-1
           uc=uc+1
           gc=0`

   ```
   if uc>nu:
       print("The lowest average is ", low, " and the highest is ", high)
       #Need to print the names that go along with the grades
   ```

   """

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thank you so much for your reply. I saved your code and ran it and got the issue you addressed in your first point. I was not getting that issue before. The code in the description of my main post has been updated with comments juanpa.arrivillaga made. It is returning the output with no system errors, but is not returning the correct numbers for the averages. I haven't learned the dictionary method yet, so I assume something with the way I wrote the initial code isn't agreeing with it?

Comment: @Hannah : If you want student name who obtained max average it is better to use dictionary. You can use other ways but it will be cumbersome

Comment: I'm still getting the loop of input at the beginning. Are you getting this as well or am I probably entering it into my system wrong? Looking at my class material it seems like the closest thing in the material is the return function, but that seems like just another way to print?

Comment: Okay, I'm not getting the looping issue anymore! But I am getting this return: 
  File "C:/Users/Hannah/.spyder-py3/untitled0.py", line 45, in grade
    maxkey, maxvalue = max(dict.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: I changed the syntax to dict because dct wasn't turning up for me

Comment: Great, that worked! Thank you so much. Just out of curiosity, are there other ways to print the items from the dictionary? My professor was doing work with the return function in our course notes. I'm just wondering because I haven't learned the dictionary function yet so I'm not sure if this will be an advanced solution for a 010-level course.

Comment: actually `dct.iteritems()` is in python2.7 but in python 3 its replaced with `dct.items()` and that is the only way to retreive dictionay key value paira

Comment: Will do. Additionally, how would I add to return the min value as well? I tried copying the code for the max value and it only returned the max val **edit: sorry, mistyped. Got it to work

Comment: use `minkey, minvalue = min(dct.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])` you have to use minkey and minvalue variables in your print statement